# PHP - How to initialize an array and exclude some elements depending on a condition

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to initialize an array:

```
$arr = array(
  "date_edited"  => time(),
  "date_added"   => ($action == "add" ? time() : NULL)
  ...
);
```

I use this array to update a database table.

Note the 2nd key, date_added. What I would like "date_added" not to be included in the array if $action is not "add". So in this case ($action != "add"), isset($arr['date_added']) should be **false**.

Is it possible right at the array's initialization? (I tried with NULL, but didn't work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep using your method and just [filter it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) on declaration:

Example:

```
$action = "remove";
$arr = array_filter(array(
  "date_edited"     => time(),
  "date_added"      => ($action == "add"     ? time() : NULL),
  "date_removed"    => ($action == "remove"  ? time() : NULL),
  "date_approved"   => ($action == "approve" ? time() : NULL)
));

var_dump($arr);
```

Will output:

```
array(2) { ["date_edited"]=> int(1313072949) ["date_removed"]=> int(1313072949) }
```

Comment: Instead of `NULL` you might want to use `FALSE` because that is what no callback says it will do.  From the docs: `"If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE will be removed."`

Comment: That's what it says but it behaves as `empty()`. Empty array, 0, '0', FALSE, NULL, '' will all return FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
  "date_edited"  => time(), //...
);

if($action == "add") {
 arr["date_added"] = time();
}
```

//EDIT

If you want to do it on initialization, you can keep your code but then have to check for `is_null($arr['date_added'])` instead of `isset(...)`.

Comment: Yes, that's how I currently do it. But I'd like to simplify the code and make it more readable by adding all the elements right at the initialization. Not sure if it is possible though..

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to update the value of a field in a db, don't pass that field.

```
$arr = array(
  "date_edited"  => time(),
  "date_added"   => time(),
  ...
);

$tmp = $arr; // copy $arr into $tmp in case you don't want to mess with the original

if($action == "add")
{
  unset($tmp['date_added']);
}

// do your sql operation using $tmp
```